# want yadcf filter multiselect options based on another filter value

Tags: yadcf

I am using yadcf 0.9.3.

I have data similar to the following

```
race1,event1,otherfields
race1,event1,otherfields
race1,event2,otherfields
race1,event2,otherfields
race2,event3,otherfields
race2,event4,otherfields
```

I want to be able to select race (e.g., race1) with one filter, then have event filter multiselect show only appropriate events (in this case event1, event2). And when I select another race (e.g., race2) only those events are shown (in this case event3, event4)

I tried `cumulative_filtering = true`, but that doesn't work for my use case. First of all with `cumulative_filtering = true`, once I've selected race1, I can't change the selection to race2, also I have read other stackoverflow questions which noted that multiselect doesn't work well with cumulative_filtering because once the first options is chosen the others disappear.

This could work similar to datatables Editor [dependent()](https://editor.datatables.net/reference/api/dependent()), I suppose.

Is there any way to achieve this with the current or more recent yadcf? I reviewed 0.9.3.beta.26 (well master/latest, see https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/94a95338e697f972fa64bc79e4276fc35c8f3c40/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js), and I am not sure if the new features would work (although it's possible something can be done with exRefreshColumnFilterWithDataProp -- note doc goes off the right side of the page when reviewing through github, so formatting could be improved).

If exRefreshColumnFilterWithDataProp should be used, is there a best practice to determine the values for one column (in my case events) given a filter in another (in my case races)?

UPDATE1 with codepen test case: https://codepen.io/louking/pen/VOrYjr

Comment: Please provide a test page for your case, in addition it might be a good idea to add similar behavior to editors `dependent`

Comment: I added a test case which shows both issues using cumulative_filtering yadcf version 0.9.3.

Comment: Should I write this (dependent filter) as an issue for a feature request? I wish I had time to do a PR but there's too much work on the project I'm doing, and this is just one aspect which would improve my user's experience.